# How do you prevent the circuit card from rattling inside a ST600/640 hydrophone recorder?

Tags: soundtrap, hardware

The long circuit board in the ST600/640 hydrophone recorders can rattle if the case moves rapidly, like on a struming cable.

Answer (score 2):

[image]I found that if I wrap a velcro band around the battery pack that is closest to the end, this eliminates the rattle.  Several layers of electrical tape would probably work too. Either of these would also prevent the batteries from slipping loose if subject to an impact.  Has anyone found this to be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue and also used Velcro around the battery banks to keep the board from rattling. Here is an image of what Jay mentioned above.  [image]

Comment: This picture is really useful - thank you. Do you think you could possibly Edit Jay's post and add the photo so it doesn't show up as two separate answers, since it is the same approach?

Comment: Hi Selen,e I just made the edit. I will wait until it is approved before deleting my other answer